# Data getting overwritten with same timestamp in InfluxDB

Tags: time, database, data, load

There are some data in a csv file and it is getting overwritten if the timestamp is similar, for example:

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python
1.2.1.2,2018-08-31 11:05:28,oracle
1.3.1.3,2018-08-31 11:05:28,microsoft
1.4.2.5,2018-08-31 13:15:52,devops
```

The result in InfluxDB is coming as:

```
ip,time,name
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python
1.3.1.3,2018-08-31 11:05:28,microsoft
1.4.2.5,2018-08-31 13:15:52,devops
```

The issue is: The second-row record got overwritten by the third rows because the timestamp is same.

I want to insert all record in the InfluxDB.

Comment: check.. this helps for your issue https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/troubleshooting/frequently_encountered_issues/#writing-duplicate-points

Comment: Thanks, I have checked this link but can you tell me how I will make IP as unique value. In every file I am getting 98 records and every IP is unique. but what is the command to tell to InfluxDB to that the IP column is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Try add a unique random number or a sequence number as a tag. Adding a random number as a tag prevents influxdb from overwriting points with the exact same tags and timestamp, since they are considered different points. But there is also a slight chance of conliding.

for example:

```
ip,time,name,_random
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,65536
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,42
```

or

```
ip,time,name,_seq
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,1
1.1.1.1,2018-08-31 11:12:32,python,2
```

But, you can not use too many numbers for the same tag. Influx by default sets max-tag-per-value to 100000.

Comment: This DOES answer the question, despite that it's very short. Adding a random number as a tag prevents influxdb from overwriting points with the exact same tags and timestamp. I don't know if this is the best practice, but it IS a way.

Comment: In that case I sinserely apologise, but that snippet of information should definitely be added to the answer. Adding random numbers does otherwise seem an odd thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reviewing, I will update the answer.